# Как обработать ошибку при регистрации на Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть проект который пишу на Flask

repository - хранит в себе таблицы

service - логика

В папке service есть файл CreateNewUser.py

```
from repository.model import db, Users

# Function for create new User and Add To a database
def CreateNewUser(login, password, email, err):
    NewUser = Users(login = login, password = password, email = email, role = 1)

    try:
        db.session.add(NewUser)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        err = 'Ошибка: Такой пользователь уже существует!'
```

В main.py вызывается следующим образом:

```
@app.route('/registrequest', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def registrequest():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form.get('login')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        err = ''

        CreateNewUser(login, password, email, err)
        if len(err) != 0:
            return err
    return redirect('/')
```

По моей задумке, должен просто появиться шаблон с Текстом из **err**. Но понимаю, что

```
if len(err) != 0:
   return err
```

этот **err** не получает тот текст, что записан в **CreateNewUser.py**.

Как обработать эту ошибку, чтобы просто в шаблон вывелся текст " Ошибка: Пользователь уже существует " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать всё гораздо проще:

```
from repository.model import db, Users

# Function for create new User and Add To a database
def CreateNewUser(login, password, email):
    NewUser = Users(login = login, password = password, email = email, role = 1)

    try:
        db.session.add(NewUser)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        raise ValueError("Ошибка: Такой пользователь уже существует!")
```

и

```
@app.route('/registrequest', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def registrequest():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form.get('login')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        email = request.form.get('email')

        try:
            CreateNewUser(login, password, email)
        except ValueError as e:
            return e
    return redirect('/')
```